# CSS Fixed element with input focus fixture but preventing animate scrolltop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a fixed box at the footer of a product page, which is working fine now with this fix applied:

```
html, body {
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling : touch !important;
    overflow: auto !important;
    height: 100%;
}
```

As it fixed the problem on iPhone where you focused in the QTY input field and it pulled it down to the bottom of the page; that fix above now sorted that and works perfect!

However, the accordion tabs on the page dont work a expected, if I remove that fix for the other issue they work but with they don't.

I think it might be easier to do a fix for the scrollto tab as I have searched and read about the fix focus issue; what it does when you click a tab now is just goes to the top of the page and does not scroll to the active tab. Here is the function:

```
function scrollToTab(x) {
  $("html, body").animate({
    scrollTop: $(x).offset().top - 10
  }, scrollSpeed);
}
```

I am sure it is the html, body its trying to animate and scroll so anyone know what I can maybe change to this to get both working?

Maybe only set those styles / fix on html, body when input focused and remove when not? that might work.